# cURL request to Python (using multipart/form-data)

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, sesame

I am trying to translate this cURL request:

```
curl -X POST "endpoint" -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F "config=@conf.ttl"
```

So far I've got this:

```
requests.post(
     endpoint,
     headers={"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
     files={"config": ("conf.ttl", open("conf.ttl", "rb"), "text/turtle")}
)
```

But it doesn't work quite as expected. What is it I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure, but I believe you want to change `'config'` to `'file'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be explicitly setting "multipart/form-data". It is overwriting all the other part of the header set by requests ("multipart/form-data; boundary=4b9...",). There is no need to set the header, requests will do that for you. You can see the request headers (requests.headers) in the example below. You can see that

```
import requests
endpoint = "http://httpbin.org/post"
r = requests.post(
     endpoint,
     files={"config": ("conf.ttl", open("conf.ttl", "rb"), "text/turtle")}
)
print r.request.headers
print r.headers
print r.text
```

gives:

```
{'Content-Length': '259', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.10.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=4b99265adcf04931964cb96f48b53a36'}
{'Content-Length': '530', 'Server': 'nginx', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Date': 'Fri, 20 May 2016 20:50:05 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "config": "curl -X POST \"endpoint\" -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -F \"config=@conf.ttl\"\n\n"
  }, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Content-Length": "259", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=4b99265adcf04931964cb96f48b53a36", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.10.0"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "84.92.144.93", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Where as your code with the explicit header gives a error to the same URL.

```
{'Content-Length': '259', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.10.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
{'Date': 'Fri, 20 May 2016 20:54:34 GMT', 'Content-Length': '291', 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server': 'nginx'}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I have accepted your answer. Does it say that somewhere in the documentation (that there is no need to explicitly set the request header) ?

Comment: No, not really but in the examples it is not used.